# Enforcing abstractmethod behavior when decorating all methods in an ABCMeta subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass, abstract-methods

I want to implement a metaclass for wrapping methods to log additional information. But I also need to have `abstractmethods`. I tried to extend `ABCMeta` but it doesn't seem to enforce the `@abstractmethod` decorator:

```
import types
import abc

def logfunc(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    def fncomposite(*args, **kwargs):
        rt = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Executed %s" % fn.__name__)
        return rt
    return fncomposite

class LoggerMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        for name, value in dct.items():
            if type(value) is types.FunctionType or type(value) is types.MethodType:
                dct[name] = logfunc(value)
        return super(LoggerMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoggerMeta, cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if cls.__abstractmethods__:
            raise TypeError("{} has not implemented abstract methods {}".format(
                cls.__name__, ", ".join(cls.__abstractmethods__)))


class Foo(metaclass=LoggerMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class FooImpl(Foo):
    def a(self):
        pass

v = FooImpl()
v.foo()
```

When I run this it prints `Executed foo`. However I expected it to fail because I have not implemented `foo` in `FooImpl`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well ... you decorated (replaced) your abstractmethod with a non abstract function in your metaclass `__new__`. What did you expect?

Comment: You could instead only decorate non abstract members. That should work.

Comment: Well I also presumed that to be the case. But I want abstract members logged as well. Guess I am not familiar with how ABCMeta is implemented. I thought as long a we don't change the function name it shouldn't matter which actual function it points to when it comes to the abstract method check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you decorate a function (or method) and return a different object you effectively replaced the function (method) with something else. In your case the method isn't an `abstractmethod` any more. It's a function that wraps an `abstractmethod`, which isn't recognized as abstract by `ABCMeta`.

The fix is relatively easy in this case: [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
import functools  # <--- This is new

def logfunc(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    @functools.wraps(fn)   # <--- This is new
    def fncomposite(*args, **kwargs):
        rt = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Executed %s" % fn.__name__)
        return rt
    return fncomposite
```

That's all you need to change.

And with that change in place it correctly raises:

```
TypeError: Foo has not implemented abstract methods foo
```

However you don't need `LoggerMeta.__init__` anymore. You can simply let `ABCMeta` handle the case when there are un-implemented abstract methods. Without the `LoggerMeta.__init__` method this will raise another exception:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class FooImpl with abstract methods foo
```

The `functools.wraps` not only correctly handles abstractmethods. It also preserves the signature and documentation of the decorated function (and some other nice stuff). If you use decorators to simply wrap functions you almost always want to use `functools.wraps`!